# Scanner NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm having a problem with my Java assignment. I'm getting an unexpected exception, specifically:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I am using `Scanner(System.in)` and the program is continually reading nothing and repeating the "invalid format" exception text. If I enter a correctly valued `int`, the first part passes and then the `double` part immediately goes into this exception. If I enter an incorrectly valued `int`, then it starts looping the exception.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getValidInt("Enter an integer from 5 to 50",5,50);
        getValidDouble("Enter a double from 5.0 to 50.0",5.0,50.0);
        getValidString("Enter a string with length from 5 to 8 characters",5,8);
    }


    public static int getInt(String prompt)
    {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int i = 0;
       boolean isValid;
       do
       {
          try
          {
             System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
             i = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
             isValid = true;
          } 
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println(e);
              System.out.print("Invalid Format: ");
              isValid = false;
          }
       }
       while (isValid == false);
       sc.close();
       return i;
    }

    public static int getValidInt(String prompt, int min, int max)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        do
        {
            i = getInt(prompt);
            if(i < min) System.out.println("Value must be >= " + min);
            else if(i > max) System.out.println("Value must be <= " + max);
            else isValid = true;
        } while (isValid == false);

        return i;
    }

    public static double getDouble(String prompt)
    {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       double i = 0.0;
       boolean isValid;
       do
       {
          try
          {
             System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
             i = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
             isValid = true;
          } 
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println(e);
              System.out.println("Invalid Format: ");
              isValid = false;
          }
       } while (isValid == false);
       sc.close();
       return i;
    }

    public static double getValidDouble(String prompt, double min, double max)
    {
        int i = 0;   
        boolean isValid = false;
        do
        {
            i = getInt(prompt);
            if(i < min) System.out.println("Value must be >= " + min);
            else if(i > max) System.out.println("Value must be <= " + max);
            else isValid = true;
        } while (isValid == false);

        return i;
    }

    public static String getString(String prompt)
    {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String i="";
       boolean isValid;
       do
       {
          try
          {
             System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
             i = sc.nextLine();
             isValid = true;
          } 
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.print("Invalid Format: ");
              isValid = false;
          }
       } while (isValid == false);
       sc.close();
       return i;
    }

    public static String getValidString(String prompt, int min, int max)
    {
        String i;
        boolean isValid = false;

        do
        {
            i = getString(prompt);
            if(i.length() < min) System.out.println("String must be more than "       + min + " characters.");
            else if(i.length() > max) System.out.println("String must be more     than " + max + " characters.");
            else isValid = true;
        } while (isValid == false);

        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have more than one `Scanner` that you close, which closes the underlying `InputStream`, therefore another `Scanner` can no longer read from the same `InputStream` and a `NoSuchElementException` results.

For console apps, use a single `Scanner` to read from `System.in`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, eclipse was giving me a warning about not closing scanner and I wouldn't have added that otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you print out the same message in all three places where an exception is caught, it is difficult to say with any certainty what is going on:

- Use `printStackTrace()` to find out where the exception is happening
- Don't catch `Exception` like that.  Catch the exceptions that you are expecting and that your code is designed to handle.  If you catch `Exception` you could end up catching all sorts of *unexpected* exceptions (NPE, end of file, etc) ... and **incorrectly** reporting them as "Invalid format".

Comment: +1. Also, in `getValidDouble(String prompt, double min, double max)` you have `int i = 0;`, are you sure you want i to be an `int`?

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  Note that the original version of the question did not say what the exception was.