# java - specifiing Int as input with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i have a function to read user input. it takes a parameter to choose reading Ints or Strings. When i try to make sure that it  reads only Ints with while(!sc.hasNextInt()) it works, but only when i step it in debug mode. whenever i try to use it while program is running it throws an exception regardless of input being a number or characters.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Databaz.ctecka(Databaz.java:14)
at Databaz.main(Databaz.java:38)
```

this points me to sc.next(); line in my function:

```
    static String ctecka(int volba)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String vystup = "vystup";
    if(volba == 1)
    {
        int cislo = 0;
        while(!sc.hasNextInt())
            sc.next();                //this is where exception points

        cislo = sc.nextInt();   
        vystup = Integer.toString(cislo);
    }
    if(volba == 2)
    {
        vystup = sc.nextLine();     
    }
    sc.close();
    return vystup;
}
```

function is being used from code:

```
int volba = Integer.parseInt(ctecka(1));     //it returns String so i parse it
```

Comment: Does it ask you for input?

Comment: there is system.out.println("input: "); before it is being called and then there is a     int variable = Integer.parseInt(myScannerFunction(1)); call

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you close your scanner `sc.close();` which closes your inputStream then you try to access it again ([have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15443510/1638739)), so to solve your problem, generalize your scanner variable, and then close it only when you finish all the `ctecka()` method calls, like the following:

```
Scanner sc;
private void some_method(){
    int volba1 = Integer.parseInt(ctecka(1));
    int volba2 = Integer.parseInt(ctecka(1));
    int volba3 = Integer.parseInt(ctecka(2));
    int volba4 = Integer.parseInt(ctecka(3));
    sc.close();
}

String ctecka(int volba){
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String vystup = "vystup";
    if(volba == 1)
    {
        int cislo = 0;
        while(!sc.hasNextInt())
            sc.next();

        cislo = sc.nextInt();   
        vystup = Integer.toString(cislo);
    }
    if(volba == 2)
    {
        vystup = sc.nextLine();     
    }
    return vystup;
}
```