# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementExceptionat java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried the solution `scannername.hasNextInt()` and it still doesn't work. Under `CalculateGPA` the error is thrown after the line "enter marks for subject1". `RegisterStudent` only takes in subject names and their credits.

```
class CalculateGPA {
    RegisterStudent s;
    int scoreSum=0;

    CalculateGPA(RegisterStudent std){
        s=std;
        System.out.println("\nIn calculate\n");
    }

    void findGPA() throws NumberFormatException,InvalidGPAException {
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    int marks1,marks2,marks3;

    String result; 
    System.out.println("\nEnter the marks for "+s.subject1);
    if(sc.hasNext()){
        marks1=sc.nextInt();
        result=findGrade(marks1);
        System.out.println(s.subject1+"             "+result);
    }
}
```

My main class:

```
public class all {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RegisterStudent s1=new RegisterStudent();
        //RegisterStudent s2=new RegisterStudent();
        s1.getBranch("ISE");
        s1.getName("Saniya");
        try{
            s1.register();
        }
        catch(CreditLimitException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        CalculateGPA cal=new CalculateGPA(s1);
        try{
            cal.findGPA();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(InvalidGPAException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: I notice that many other people who had this error had closed a Scanner.  Are you closing a scanner elsewhere in your code, before this runs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner NoSuchElementException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443383/scanner-nosuchelementexception)